# Wordpress SQL - How to Check for Category?

Tags: database, sql

I'm using the following SQL (wrapped in php) to find posts in a wordpress database:

```
$sql = "
    SELECT
        p.*
    FROM
        {$wpdb->prefix}most_popular mp
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}posts p ON mp.post_id = p.ID
    WHERE
        p.post_type IN ( $holder ) AND
        p.post_status = 'publish'
    {$order}
    LIMIT %d
";
```

And I want to add an additional condition that the post be in a specific category.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

> And I want to add an additional condition that the post be in a
>   specific category. Any thoughts?

`JOIN`ing on the taxonomy tables is complicated. Unless you have a good reason why you *have to* use `SQL`, don't. Use [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

```
$args = array(
  'post_type'     => $holder,
  'numberposts'   => -1,
  'post_status'   => array('publish'),
  'category_name' => 'cat-slug', // slug not strictly the name
  'orderby'       => $order,
  'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
);
$qry = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I am guessing about the content of some of your variables.

If you must use pure `SQL`, run the query above but add `var_dump($qry->request)` and you will have the generated `SQL` dumped to the screen. That will give you an idea of what has to happen.

Comment: The reason why sql is the {$wpdb->prefix}most_popular mp table.

Comment: Ok. I see that now. You can still join on that table using the `posts_join` filter though. But whatever you decide, the `var_dump` suggested above will give you the `SQL` you need in broad outline, at least.